# Jenkins SSH Plugin / SSH Agent plugin: Exception:timeout: socket is not established

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins, jsch

I'm getting an error while using "**Execute shell scripts on remote host using ssh**" step in BUILD Step in Jenkins. Has anybody faced this issue?

Jenkins version is latest: 1.628. 
SSH Plugin is 2.4
SSH Agent plugin is 1.8

**Error:**

```
15:57:56 [SSH] Exception:timeout: socket is not established
15:57:56 com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established
15:57:56    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:386)
15:57:56    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:182)
15:57:56    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:150)
15:57:56    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SSHSite.createSession(SSHSite.java:141)
15:57:56    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SSHSite.executeCommand(SSHSite.java:151)
15:57:56    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SSHBuilder.perform(SSHBuilder.java:60)
15:57:56    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
15:57:56    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
15:57:56    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
15:57:56    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
15:57:56    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
15:57:56    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
15:57:56    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
15:57:56    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
15:57:56    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
15:57:56 Build step 'Execute shell script on remote host using ssh' marked build as failure
15:57:56 Collecting metadata...
15:57:56 Metadata collection done.
15:57:56 Started calculate disk usage of build
15:57:56 Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
15:57:56 Started calculate disk usage of workspace
15:57:56 Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
15:57:56 Notifying upstream projects of job completion
15:57:56 Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: are you able to run the code under *jenkins* user inside the box  ?

Comment: Yes, it works there (jenkins machine itself) or also from any other source machine to the target machine.

Comment: I am not sure your situation, but I ran into the similar issue when I was trying to execute command on remote machine where *ssh* connection was with `.pem` key. Are using one?  The problem was that *jenkins* could not find in local keystore certificate to connect. I used [InstallCert](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert) tool to do that.

Comment: To me it seems like most probably.. coming due to either me upgrading Jenkins version (from 1.623 to 1.628) or upgrading SSH Plugin ... I'll try and update if that's the case.

Comment: One of the co-worked pointed out that.. From here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin 
Version of the plugin 2.5 is going to have ssh timeout setting that can be configured Looks like that is what you are hitting on these, the socket connection is taking some time to open and its aborting as failure. My job was working fine but seems like when I bulk updated bunch of plugins (under Manage Plugins > Update) .. it updated SSH Plugin from 2.3 to 2.4 version. So, either I have to wait for version 2.5 to come (for SSH Plugin) or revert back SSH Plugin to version 2.3

Comment: I have Jenkins *v1.627* , SSH Plugin *v2.4* and SSH Agent plugin *v1.4.1* :) decided to stick w/ old one for now..I think issue is in version compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting/downgrading SSH Plugin to version# **2.3** worked and now I'm not getting the error. Jenkins version is still 1.628/latest.